# PdfReader node.js

Tags: node.js, parsing, pdf

I am new to NodeJS. I am trying to parse a PDF file with PdfReader. Let's say we have the next sequence of code :

```
    var PdfReader = require("pathto/PdfReader");

    aux = '';
    new PdfReader().parseFileItems(pdf_file, function(err, item) {
        if (err)
              callback(err);
        else if(item.text) 
              aux = item.text;
    });

    console.log(' aux = ' + aux);
```

Let's say the last item is 'car' . That means the output has to be 'aux = car'. But my output is 'aux = ' . The problem is that outside the reading function I can't see the value of a variable which was declared before the reading function. 
Can someone explain to me what is happening and what I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I suppose that parseFileItems is asynchonius function (google about this) and you should log result in this way:

```
` var PdfReader = require("pathto/PdfReader");

    aux = '';
    new PdfReader().parseFileItems(pdf_file, function(err, item) {
        if (err)
              callback(err);
        else if(item.text) 
        {
              aux = item.text;
              console.log(' aux = ' + aux);
        }

    });

    `
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the end of file by checking for !item and then print the previous item.text .

```
var PdfReader = require("pathto/PdfReader");
aux = '';
new PdfReader().parseFileItems(pdf_file, function(err, item) {
    if (err)
          callback(err);
    else if(!item)
        console.log("aux + " + aux)
    else if(item.text)
          aux = item.text;       
});
```